# Laravel: Ajax error, can't figure out how to set the right URL

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

right now im having an Ajax problem.. I've been googleing for the past 3 hours and can't figure it out. Basically I want my form to submit without my page reloading. Simple Ajax right? Still not working for me :(

Here is my Code:

```
$('#counter').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/games/question/update',
        data: $('form#counter').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json'
        // key: value
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

My Routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'games', 'as' => 'games.'], function () {
Route::get('/', 'GamesController@index')->name('index');
Route::get('/winner', 'GamesController@winner');
Route::put('/question/update', 'GamesController@update');
Route::get('/question/{id}/', 'GamesController@counter');
Route::post('/', 'GamesController@store')->name('store'); });
```

My Form looks like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('games.update', $player->id) }}" id="counter"> ... </form>
```

I need this form to submit with ajax because i've got a second form on the same page..

As you maybe can tell im new to Laravel and php in general, if you need anything else here is my git repo of the project:

https://github.com/dirtypaulmfz/Quiztopher.git

Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to [form method spoofing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#form-method-spoofing).  You need to set the `_method` parameter when hitting a route that does use `get` or `post`. Your form data should include:

```
_method: 'patch' // or put
```

There is a [helper method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-method-field):

```
{{ method_field('patch') }}
```

As well as a blade directive:

```
@method('put')
```